# How to generate Payslip for last month in OpenERP

Tags: odoo

I facing this problem in Payslip, Our client policy is payslip generating is every 5 of the date, I creating a payslip for employee it load current month only, but there is no payslip generated on last month. In case I select last month From Date Oct 1 & To Date Oct 31 its date will calculate the Number Of Working day is current Date. is this bug?. Now I want when I create payslip last month from and To date want to calculate Number Of working Days is last month days only I need . How to solve this?

Comment: Do you have some code ? Or isn't this programming related ?

Comment: It is a functionality of OpenERP, if there is no solution means we have to develop.

Comment: 'date_from': lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-01'),
'date_to': lambda *a: str(datetime.now() + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=+1, day=1, days=-1))[:10], date_from & date_to is a field name, here I want last month date 1/10/2013 to date is 31/10/2013.